# PushCreate children nodes in Kendo HierarchicalDataSource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to show a Kendo TreeView configured with remote data, but prefill the first two levels with data loaded directly from the html.

For that, I want to use the [pushCreate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-pushCreate) method of the Kendo dataSource to add the initial elements to the tree:

```
homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: { read: { url: serviceRoot + "/Employees", dataType: "jsonp" } },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "EmployeeId",
            hasChildren: "HasEmployees"
        }
    }
});

// Adding root
homogeneous.pushCreate({"EmployeeId":2,"FullName":"Andrew Fuller","HasEmployees":true,"ReportsTo":null});

// Adding children
homogeneous.pushCreate([
    {"EmployeeId":1,"FullName":"Nancy Davolio","HasEmployees":false,"ReportsTo":2},
    {"EmployeeId":3,"FullName":"Janet Leverling","HasEmployees":false,"ReportsTo":2},
    {"EmployeeId":4,"FullName":"Margaret Peacock","HasEmployees":false,"ReportsTo":2},
    {"EmployeeId":5,"FullName":"Steven Buchanan","HasEmployees":true,"ReportsTo":2},
    {"EmployeeId":8,"FullName":"Laura Callahan","HasEmployees":false,"ReportsTo":2}
]);

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: homogeneous,
    dataTextField: "FullName"
});
```

However, the children elements are added to the root level (you can see this running [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/AjIti/7)).

There is a `schema.model.children` configuration to set the property that holds the children inside the root element and I can add all in one go, but if I use that then the dataSource stops working with remote data (you can see that running [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/AjIti/5)).

So the question is, is there a way to use pushCreate to add elements as children of another one on a HierarchicalDataSource?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer while writting the question :)

It seems like if I simply use `items` as the key for the children, I don't need to specify the `schema.model.children` option so the tree still works with remote data:

```
homogeneous.pushCreate(
    {"EmployeeId":2,"FullName":"Andrew Fuller","HasEmployees":true,"ReportsTo":null,
        "items": [
            {"EmployeeId":1,"FullName":"Nancy Davolio","HasEmployees":false,"ReportsTo":2},
            {"EmployeeId":3,"FullName":"Janet Leverling","HasEmployees":false,"ReportsTo":2},
            {"EmployeeId":4,"FullName":"Margaret Peacock","HasEmployees":false,"ReportsTo":2},
            {"EmployeeId":5,"FullName":"Steven Buchanan","HasEmployees":true,"ReportsTo":2},
            {"EmployeeId":8,"FullName":"Laura Callahan","HasEmployees":false,"ReportsTo":2}
        ]
    }
);
```

[Here's the working example](http://dojo.telerik.com/AjIti/8).

I don't know if that's and unintended feature but works for adding a whole subtree to the root (which solves my problem). However the question still stands, can I use pushCreate to add a child element to another one?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work! The second level still gets loaded from remote. When you change the url of the HierarchicalDataSource you see that only the parent will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by appending the node element with [append](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/node#methods-append). See this example by telerik: http://dojo.telerik.com/AjIti/32